# Cannot access static build.html from my project root

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, maven-plugin

I am trying to access the static HTML page which has the information of the build process, and it gets generated using maven war plugin. However, when I try to access the `build.html` generated in my root of the project nothing is showing up or inaccessible. However, when I tried to access any HTML file under my `src/main/webapp/static`, then am able to access by using the URL: `http://localhost:8180/MyProject/static/about/build.html`.

But cannot access by this way which probably I am looking for: `http://localhost:8180/MyProject/build.html`.

Structure inside my MyProject.war

```
MyProject.war

META-IN

static

WEB-INF

build.html
```

Maven War Plugin

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/static/about</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

WebConfiguration class (web.xml)

```
public class AppWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppWebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

AppWebConfiguration (Spring Configuration)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackages")
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");

    }


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Spring Security Configuration

```
 @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").hasRole(ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole(ADMIN)

            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/errorpage");  

        }
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Comment: Thanks.. I have added few more configuration files, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");
```

Comment: No luck! I believe the below line will only be helpful if the files are in WEB-INF, registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/");  what about if it is outside the WEB-INF? As build.html are generated at root level or outside the WEB-INF

Comment: Is my spring security causing any issues to access the build.html?

Comment: Yes, because the spring security, so Do you want override the target directory? you can config the `<targetPath>yourPath e.g.WEB-INF</targetPath>`, [Detail see here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html#Overriding_the_default_destination_directory)

Comment: Yes I am trying to override the target directory. I initially started with having the  <targetPath>src/main/webapp</targetPath> in my maven war plugin configuration but this was not creating the build.html. However when I set to <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath> it was creating the build.html file but is not accessible when I try to access by url localhost/MyProject/build.html

Comment: If I do not use the targetPath then it creates the file outside the WEB-INF which is at the root level like I mention above about the structure of my war, but is not accessible using the url localhost/MyProject/build.html

Comment: Or you can add `.antMatchers("/build.html").anonymous()`

Comment: Sorry, not the spring security, because no handler handle the build.html request, so you need add the `addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations(‌​"/WEB-INF/")`, or you can write it in controller, I think that's no need.

Comment: if the resource is out site the WEB-INF, you need to config the right path for the ResourceLocations

Comment: How to access that in Resource Location anything which is outside the WEB-INF or at the project root level? May be like this add Resource Locations(‌​"/**")  or Resource Locations("/")? Though I have tried both of this option but no luck

Comment: I have just added <targetPath>src/main/rescource</targetPath> in my maven config pointing to my classpath, though files are being generated there in my target folder or in my war.  Can I add the classpath location to my addResourceLocation("classpath:build.xml")?

Comment: ResourceHandler is usually for static resource, like JS,CSS

Comment: Why the targetPath is src/main/rescource ?

Comment: Oh yes i agree classpath is not needed in targetPath. I have tried all means but unable to access it from the root though my build.html generates on the build out of WEB-INF and lies at the root of my war so not sure what it is stopping to access it directly as these are static files

Comment: Though I am able to access anything which is at this location registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/"); Though maven is not generating the files here at this location as it is generating it either outside the WEB-INF or inside. This static directory I have under /src/main/webapp/static